# How to delete database values using Array

Tags: c#, sql, database

```
DataView view = new DataView(dt);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "ProductID");
DataRow[] myRows = distinctValues.Select();
```

i use this code for selecting certain column inside a DataTable. Now how can i use myRows[] values to delete the values in my database? For example:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID = myRows[]";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

assuming that myRows[] has multiple values.

Comment: it will depend on what your backend is, assuming you don't want to do a loop or use a DataAdapter

Comment: Do you mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause?

Comment: @ConradFrix: maybe using loop can be more easy to understand because the link MikeSmithDev gave me is too hard for me to understand how it works. im sorry, just a noob.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `IN` operator, and create corresponding string:

```
var idList = String.Join(",", myRows.Select(u => u["ColumnName"].ToString()));
string sql = string.Format("delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID IN({0})", idList);
```

you need to create something like this:

```
string sql = "delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID IN (1, 2, 3)"
```

Comment: `string sql = "delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID IN (1, 2, 3)"` where should i put this? is it different in this `string sql = string.Format("delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID IN({0})", idList);` ?

Comment: no, this `string sql = "delete from tblindividualproduct where ProductID IN (1, 2, 3)"`, or something like that is what you need to create finally, totally you need to create an `delete` statement using `IN` operator using `string.Format()`